# RxJava bufferWithTimeOrCount() implementation?

Tags: rx-java

Using RxJava, I need to buffer up a stream of items into groups of 3, but if more than 500ms elapse *between incoming items*, flush the buffer.

The **bufferWithTimeOrCount()** operator is exactly what I'm looking for, but it only seems to be implemented for [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) and [Rx.NET](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/new-drop-of-Rx-NET--JS-available), and I need to use RxJava for this one.

Is there a way to duplicate the behavior of **bufferWithTimeOrCount()** and get what I'm after with the existing RxJava 1.x operators?

`buffer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 3)` tries to emit a new list every 500ms, not taking into account the time since the last item.

I've been trying to make things work with `buffer(bufferClosingSelector)` (see [RxJava Buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)).  I set up a sequence that emits items with an increasing delay between them:

```
Observable<Long> emitter = Observable
    .range(1, 9)
    .flatMap(n -> {
        return Observable.just(n).delay(n * n * 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    })
    .timeInterval()
    .map(interval -> interval.getIntervalInMilliseconds());
```

Then I tried using `debounce()` to flush the buffer when the time between items grew over 500ms:

```
emitter
    .buffer(emitter.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Which seems to work, producing sequences like:

```
[51, 150, 250, 352, 449]
[551]
[650]
[749]
[850]
```

Then I tried to create a counter to flush the buffer after every three items, thinking that I could just `merge()` it with the debounced observable:

```
emitter
    .buffer(emitter
       .scan(1L, (n, x) -> n + 1)   // count the items up from 1
       .filter(n -> ((n % 3) == 0)  // emit every three items
    )
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

But the results weren't as successful:

```
[50]
[152, 248, 350]
[452, 550, 650, 749]
[]
```

If I output the intervals, it appears the counter is running asynchronously to the batching observable, so a race condition is occurring between the time it fires and the time the batch actually gets released:

```
emitter
    .buffer(emitter
       .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i))
       .scan(1L, (n, x) -> n + 1)   // count the items up from 1
       .filter(n -> ((n % 3) == 0)  // emit every three items
    )
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Produces:

```
i = 63
i = 150
[51, 150]
i = 249
i = 350
i = 451
[249, 351]
i = 550
i = 650
i = 750
[450, 550, 650, 750]
i = 850
[850]
```

...and now I'm kind of stumped.

That was long, but TL;DR: Is there a way to duplicate the behavior of **bufferWithTimeOrCount()** and get what I'm after with the existing RxJava 1.x operators? Thanks!

Comment: In 2.x, there is an overloaded version which let's you restart the time window: `buffer(long timespan, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, int count, Callable<U> bufferSupplier, boolean restartTimerOnMaxSize)`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: after looking at the problem again I realized this solution would always emit for every 3rd item regardless if it already emitted due to a debounce. I cannot immediately think of a way to 'reset' the counting buffer after a debounce.

The problem is that by using `emitter` twice you create two independent streams with non-deterministic behavior since the scheduler is involved.

The key is combining the `buffer(...)`, `debounce(...)` and `publish(...)` operators:

```
emitter.publish(source -> {
    // Create the buffer here using a shared source
    return source.buffer(Observable.defer(() ->
         // Merge these reasons for closing the buffer
         Observable.merge(
             // Either after 500 ms
             source.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
             // or every 3 items
             source.buffer(3)
         )
    ))
})
```

I'm  not able to test this solution, but the comments should explain the idea behind it. The `Observable.defer` ensures the observables responsible for closing the windows are created after the original source.

Comment: That's true. Using the `scan()` method to count the items (like I mentioned in the question) opens the possibility of appending a `takeUntil(debounceObservable).repeat()` to reset the counter when a debounce occurs. But that requires the counter to be working reliably in the first place.